# HP Pavillion Does not start up, even the installation disc does not start

Tags: windows-10, hp-pavilion

I have a HP Pavillion Laptop with Windows 10. Suddenly today it does not start.

The Windows 10 logo appears, but it remains on the screen and does not continue.

I've tried to do a clean install with a Windows 10 (USB and CD) but it's the same situation, the installation disc begins, the Windows 10 logo appears,  and does not continue to a desktop display.

I've removed the battery and I've tried with power supply only, but it's the same situation.

Comment: In order to boot to the installation media, you will have to change the boot order.  Did you do that before you attempted to boot to the installation media?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes , i start the boot menu pressing F9 and then i choose the installation disk.

Comment: How was the installation media created?  Do you have Legacy/CM enabled or disabled currently?

Comment: The installation media is working correctly on other Laptop. I have Legacy enabled.This laptop was formatted and installed using the same installation media 2 weeks ago. Until today was working correctly.

Comment: Sounds like a hardware fault.... probably hard disk fault.Sounds like the interrogation/reading of the hard disk is having problems and causing the hang.

Comment: @Kinnectus i've tried with HDD Regenerator (from dos) and the entire Hard disk was scanned without any problem.

Comment: Tried removing/re-seating the RAM?

Comment: @Kinnectus yes , the same situation. I've tried also a DOS program for testing the RAM , and no problems where found.

Comment: DId you install Windows on a GPT or MBR partition?  Enabling Legacy Mode on a Windows 10 device seems odd, you don't typically install Windows 10, on a MBR partition.

Comment: @Ramhound I've installed 2 weeks ago using a MBR Partition. Everything was working correctly until now. Why ? Windows 10 can work in MBR or GPT. i have other Pc running Windows 10 on MBR and are working  very well.But anyway , why the installation media does not start ?

Comment: I think we all need more info for this. Try booting to safe mode (you can access it via F8 at boot). If it gets to a desktop have a look for any errors in event viewer - it might also cure the boot problem, so try a restart. If you can't get to a desktop, can you tell us what the last line displayed was or if it blue screened and the error?

Comment: @Greig i try to boot on safe mode , but it's the same problem , windows logo appear and it remains on the screen and does not continue. The same problem occur if i try to start from Hard drive or from installation media.

Comment: @antoni Safe mode should come up with a black screen with white writing on it and it shouldn't show the windows logo at all. I don't think you can start it from install media, so make sure you've removed any usb sticks or dvds. The install media will also have a startup repair option that you can try.

Comment: @Greig I know how Safe mode should look , but in my laptop even when i choose safe mode , the windows logo is showing. And when i've tested safe mode i have removed the installation media.